# Are there spectral Galerkin methods for PDE of the form $\partial_tu=\nabla\cdot f(\nabla u)\nabla u$?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Question is in the title. The nonlinearity due to the term $f(\nabla u)$ makes it difficult to directly apply the spectral Galerkin method as it can be done for PDE of the form $\partial_tu=\nabla\cdot a(t,\;\cdot\;)\nabla u$. Are there still spectral Galerkin methods available?

*EDIT*: Or is it considered to be a legitimate idea to linearize the term $f(\nabla u)$ somehow so that ordinary spectral Galerkin is applicable?

Comment: if you linearize and show the dropped part will not affect much, then it still works.